# name for cut-out piece of earth

Tags: synonyms

What is the piece of grass that comes off when a golf ball is hit called?

I kind of vaguely remember seeing it in the Tom and Jerry Cartoon once; and it was called a pivot, but I just searched for it and they say pivot is a motion in golf.

Comment: Hi Hax.  Can you TICK AN ANSWER?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Divot** (you were almost there with 'pivot'!)

> Divot: A piece of turf lifted when ball is struck.

Source: [Golf Vocabulary](http://www.salzkammergut.at/en/detail/article/golf-vocabulary.html); [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/divot)

Comment: Tim Romano had already given the answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I was composing my answer at about the same time as Tim Romano. I submitted just after him.

Comment: The '1hr' vs '2hr' contrast seems to have disappeared now; there is a rounding (or rather lack of sensible rounding) glitch on the site.

Comment: Thanks Julie. I would have wondered why if I wasn't that close, because I vividly remember Tom creating a ditch while trying to hit the ball; all the while, the sign read "please replace DIVOTS" :)

Comment: Yvw @haxkalibrr :)

Answer (score 2):

The piece of sod that gets cut out by the golf club is called a *divot*.

Comment: It also applies to the similarly-shaped piece thrown up by a horse's hoof, indeed by any action of that type. At half-time in important football matches in Britain, ground staff go on the pitch to replace the *divots* - sometimes spelled *divets*.

Comment: *Avoid the steaming divot.*